# Set Agent Classpath in - The Grinder Java

Tags: performance, testing, grinder

How do I set the agent classpath for the java grinder?

Answer (score 1):

Set it via the grinder.jvm.classpath property in your grinder.properties file.  See

http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/properties.html

For more info.